# Mapping properties that are collection types

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

Say I have a classes like this in a business layer:

```
Namespace Business
{
public class Order
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List <OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    }

public class OrderItem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }
}

and classes like this in a Model layer:

Namespace Model
{
public class OrderModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List <OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    }

public class OrderItemModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How would I map the order class in the Business Layer to the Order class in the Model layer? I have tried this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderModel>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<OrderModel, Order>();
                });
```

It does not work because of the OrderItem property in the Order class.  If I remove the OrderItem property then it works.  How do I include the orderitem property in the mapping.

I am using version 6.02 of Automapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for the collection to not be mapped automatically since names match. So far I see, you have missed the mapping between `OrderItem` and `OrderItemModel`

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<OrderItem, OrderItemModel>();
                cfg.CreateMap<OrderItemModel, OrderItem>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderModel>();
                cfg.CreateMap<OrderModel, Order>();                                 
            });
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did not realise it was that simple.  Will mark the answer in two minutes (it won't let me mark it at the moment)

Comment: I'd also recommend using ReverseMap: cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderModel>().ReverseMap();